# Float inputs for which sinf and sin return different results?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, trigonometry, c99

I'm trying to understand something about `sin` and `sinf` from `math.h`.

I understand that their types differ: the former takes and returns `double`s, and the latter takes and returns `float`s.

However, GCC still compiles my code if I call `sin` with `float` arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

int main ()
{
  float x, result;
  x = 135 / 180 * PI;
  result = sin (x);
  printf ("The sin of (x=%f) is %f\n", x, result);
  return 0;
}
```

By default, all compiles just fine (even with `-Wall`, `-std=c99` and `-Wpedantic`; I need to work with C99). GCC won't complain about me passing floats to `sin`. If I enable `-Wconversion` then GCC tells me:

```
warning: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]
   result = sin (x);
            ^~~
```

So my question is: is there a `float` input for which using `sin`, like above, and (implicitly) casting the result back to `float`, will result in a value that is different from that obtained using `sinf`?

Comment: `135 / 180 * PI` won't do what you expected. Use `135.0 / 180 * PI` instead

Comment: For `result = sin (x);` MSVC warns: *conversion from `double` to `float`, possible loss of data*.

Comment: Since most implementations of `sin` and `sinf` are not correctly rounded and differ in the way they are not correctly rounded, any answer can only be specific to one implementation (of `sin` and `sinf`).

Comment: FYI, most of the mismatches you find may be due to the fact that `sinf` is commonly implemented to have an accuracy near the precision of `float`. For example, the macOS implementation provides faithfully rounded results—most results are correctly rounded (the nearest representable value of the true sine is returned), but some are only faithfully rounded (one of the two surrounding representable values is chosen). To do that, the sine is calculated with an error less than 1 ULP of the `float` format, then rounded to `float`…

Comment: … In contrast, the `sin` routine calculates sine with much better accuracy, typically a few ULP of the `double` format. That means that if `(float) sin(x)` differs from `sinf(x)`, the former is usually the better result. If both `sin` and `sinf` returned correctly rounded results, differences between `(float) sin(x)` and `sinf(x)` would be very rare, occurring only where the sine caused a double-rounding error (a first rounding to `double` pushes it over the boundary where a `float` rounding would change). That is a one-in-2^29 occurrence.

Comment: (29 is the difference in the number of bits in a `double` significand, 53, and the number in a `float` significand, 24.)

Answer (score 4):

This will find all the `float input` values in the range `0.0` to `2 * M_PI` where `(float)sin(input) != sinf(input)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

int main(void)
{
    for (float in = 0.0; in < 2 * M_PI; in = nextafterf(in, FLT_MAX)) {
        float sin_result = (float)sin(in);
        float sinf_result = sinf(in);
        if (sin_result != sinf_result) {
            printf("sin(%.*g) = %.*g, sinf(%.*g) = %.*g\n",
                   FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, in, FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, sin_result,
                   FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, in, FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, sinf_result);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are 1020963 such inputs on my amd64 Linux system with glibc 2.32.

Answer (score 3):

This program finds three examples on my machine:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    float f, f1, f2;

    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        f = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        float f1 = sinf(f);
        float f2 = sin(f);

        if(f1 != f2) printf("jackpot: %.8f %.8f %.8f\n", f, f1, f2);
    }
}
```

I got:

```
jackpot: 0.98704159 0.83439910 0.83439904
jackpot: 0.78605396 0.70757037 0.70757031
jackpot: 0.78636044 0.70778692 0.70778686
```

Comment: Since there aren't that many floats, you could even do an exhaustive search ...

Answer (score 0):

`float` precision is approximately 6 significant figures decimal, while `double` is good for about 15.  (It is approximate because they are *binary floating point* values not *decimal floating point*).

As such for example: a `double` value `1.23456789` will become `1.23456xxx` as a `float` where `xxx` are unlikely to be `789` in this case.

Clearly not all (in fact very few) `double` values are *exactly* representable by `float`, so will change value when down-converted.

So for:

```
double a = 1.23456789 ;
float b = a ;
printf( "double: %.10f\n", a ) ;
printf( "float: %.10f\n", b ) ;
```

The result in my test was:

```
double: 1.2345678900
float:  1.2345678806
```

As you can see the `float` in fact retained 9 significant figures in this case, but it is by no means guaranteed for all possible values.

In your test you have limited the number of instances of mismatch because of the limited and finite range of `rand()` and also because `f` itself is `float`.  Consider:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned mismatch_count = 0 ;
    unsigned iterations = 0 ;
    for( double f = 0; f < 6.28318530718; f += 0.000001) 
    {
        float f1 = sinf(f);
        float f2 = sin(f);
        iterations++ ;
        if(f1 != f2)
        {
            mismatch_count++ ;
        }
    }
    printf("%f%%\n", (double)mismatch_count/iterations* 100.0);}
```

In my test about 55% of comparisons mismatched.  Changing `f` to `float`, the mismatches reduced to 1.3%.

So in your test, you see few mismatches because of the constraints of your method of generating `f` and its type. In the general case the issue is much more obvious.

In some cases you might see no mismatches - an implementation may simply implement `sinf()` using `sin()` with explicit casts. The compiler warning is for the general case of implicitly casting a `double` to a `float` without reference to any operations performed prior to the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

> However, GCC still compiles my code if I call sin with float arguments:

Yes, this is because they are implicitly converted to `double` (because `sin()` requires a float), and back to `float` (because `sin()` returns a `double`) on entering and exiting from the `sinf()` function.  See below why it is better to use `sinf()` in this case, instead of having only one function.

You have included `math.h` which has prototypes for both function calls:

```
double sin(double);
float sinf(float);
```

And so, the compiler knows that to use `sin()` it is necessary a conversion from `float` to `double` so it *compiles* a conversion before calling, and also *compiles* a conversion from `double` to `float` in the result from `sin()`.

In case you have not `#include <math.h>` and you ignored the compiler warning telling you are calling a function `sin()` with no prototype, the compiler should have also converted first the `float` to `double` (because on nonspecified argument types this is how it mus proceed) and pass the `double` data to the function (which is assumed to return an `int` in this case, that will provoke a serious *Undefined Behaviour*)

In case you have used the `sinf()` function (with the proper prototype), and passed a `float`, then no conversion should be compiled, the float is passed as such with no type conversion, and the returned value is assigned to a `float` variable, also with no conversion.  So everything goes fine with no conversion, this makes the fastest code.

In case you have used the `sinf()` function (with no prototype), and passed a `float`, this float would be converted to a `double` and passed as such to `sinf()`, resulting in undefined behaviour.  In case somehow `sinf()` returned properly, an `int` result (that could have something to do with the calculation or not, as per UB) would be converted into `float` type (should this be possible) and assigned to the result value.

In the case mentioned above, in case you are operating on `float`s, it is better to use `sinf()` as it takes less to execute (it has less iterations to do, as less precision is required in them) and the two conversions (from `float` to `double` and back from `double` to `float`) have not to be compiled in, in the binary code output by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There are some systems where computations on `float` are an order of magnitude faster than computations on `double`.  The primary purpose of `sinf` is to allow trigonometric calculations to be performed efficiently on such systems in cases where the lower precision of `float` would be adequate to satisfy application needs.  Converting a value to `float`, calling `sin`, and converting the result to `float` would always yield a value that either matched that of `sinf` or was more accurate(*), and on some implementations that would in fact be the most efficient way of implementing `sinf`.  On some other systems, however, such an approach would be more than an order of magnitude slower than using a purpose-designed function to evaluate the sine of a `float`.

(*) Note that for arguments outside the range +/- π/2, the most mathematically accurate way of computing sin(x) for an exact specified value of x might not be the most accurate way of computing what the calling code wants to know.  If an application computes `sinf(angle * (2.0f * 3.14159265f))`, when `angle` is 0.5, having the function `(double)3.1415926535897932385-(float)3.14159265f` may be more "mathematically accurate" than having it return sin(angle-(2.0f*3.14159265f)), but the latter would more accurately represent the sine of the angle the code was actually interested in.